# Could not load package "XX-SSIS-XX" No description found

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis, ssis-2012

I'm trying to run a ssis package on a remote integration server using dtutil which is being called within a stored procedure using cmdshell.  I now this isn't the best way to run a ssis package but its what I have inherited.  So doing a new deployment to a fresh new server I've created a proxy account for the cmdshell to run under, which isn't an admin account on the domain.  I have run the following scripts on my sql box

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON xp_cmdshell TO [domain\Account which will call the SP which runs the cmdshell];
EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account null
EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'domain\non admin account which the cmdshell will run as','xxxxxxx'
```

The code within the SP

```
select @DtexecParams = 'dtexec /sq xxSSIS Packagexx /ser xxremoteserver where the package isxx'
--
-- I set other connections and local parameters the package uses
-- 
exec @rc = xp_cmdshell @DtexecParams
```

Now on the remote server where the package is located I've added the domain account that the cmdshell proxy is using as a ssis operator and a datareader on the msdb database.  But when i'm running the SP to call the package I'm getting the following error returned

> Could not load package "xxxxxxxx" because of error 0x80131534.
>   Description: No description found 
>   Source:

This does not tell me much but when I run the sp as a sysadmin user all works fine, so it is more likely to be a permission issue.  I've added the proxy account user to local policy "Log on as batch job", but I still get the error.

Comment: When we created our SP to run SSIS packages, the DBA ended up using the `EXECUTE AS` clause to tie it to an admin account but I can't recall why. Is it possible the SP was created similarly and when you re-created it, that was missed?

Comment: Nice thinking but definitely did not use EXECUTE AS in the old environment.

Comment: In the end added the account as a local admin on the server!